# Installed gem much slower than source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Running an installed gem is much slower than running its local source counterpart.

Installed gem:

```
$ time wmctile switch_to Thunderbird

real  0m0.682s
user  0m0.491s
sys 0m0.091s
```

Local source:

```
$ time ./work/wmctile/bin/wmctile switch_to Thunderbird

real  0m0.197s
user  0m0.118s
sys 0m0.064s
```

Why? Could it be because of RVM, or is this a "feature" of Ruby gems in general? Is there a way to speed it up?

This is the generated bin file:

```
$ which wmctile
/home/some_user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/wmctile

$ cat $( which wmctile )
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'wmctile' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'wmctile', version
load Gem.bin_path('wmctile', 'wmctile', version)
```

Comment: I'm sure there's some overhead in RVM figuring out your current version of ruby, locating the binary and executing it.  Why not just alias `wmctile` in your bash_profile to the source?

Comment: It's a distributed gem meant to be used by other users, which would only have the gem, not the source.

Comment: @JesseSielaff It is pure ruby. The problem seems to be in the generated file, `/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks` seems to be fairly slow. I've edited the answer with the source of the generated bin file.

Comment: Can the AntiVirus be the culprit? I've seen Ruby and it's gems slowing down significantly on Windows computers running TrendMicro AV.

Comment: @RuiMarques No, the outputs are from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

RVM puts the proper directories for your Ruby version and gemset in the path whenever the RVM Ruby is set.  My PATH begins with this:

```
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/bin
```

So, I think it's the OS and not Ruby itself that is responsible for the delay.  You could test this by putting a simple shell script file in that gem bin directory, and calling it with and without its absolute location to see if you get the same difference.

Comment: I think this makes sense. A LONG path search could be responsible.